# SQL Query search that ranks one where clause over the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to to allow a user to search based on two different fields in the same table (target and name). However, if there is an exact match on target i would like that to take precedence on the order by so a row with dis as the target shows up first.

An help would be appreciated.

```
select 
    Id 
    ,[target] 
    ,[name] 
    ,[extrafield1]
    ,[extrafield2]
    ,[extrafield3]
From [inventory]
where [target] LIKE 'dil%' OR [name] LIKE '%dil%'
```

Comment: The code  seems correct .. you have error ? ..  what your question ?

Comment: no error but i would like to rank the results so if there is an exact match on target "dil" that it would take precedence over a wildcard match on name "dilney"  Right now the results dont rank at all. not sure what the best option is to rank them

Comment: `order by case when target = 'dil' then 0 when target like 'dil%' then 2  else 3 end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a widlcard on both sides of your string ie. %string% This will cause a serial read of the table.  Put it on just the right side.

```
select 
    Id 
    ,[target] 
    ,[name] 
    ,[extrafield1]
    ,[extrafield2]
    ,[extrafield3]
    ,case when [target] = 'dil' or [name] = 'dil' then 1 else 2 end as rank -- to display your ranking
From [inventory]
where [target] LIKE 'dil%' or [name] like 'dil%'   
order by case when [target] = 'dil' or [name] = 'dil' then 1 else 2 end
```

Comment: About the serial read... what if "dil" has a word in front of it and after "test dil test" but the user is searching "dil" when searching by name?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0807avoidingtablescans01.html 
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/
These two articles talk about full table scan, which is the same as a serial read.  Because of the way indexed fields are stored in the database searching on the left side of a value will cause the optimizer to ignore any indexes or even worse traverse the index one leaf at a time and not ending till it has hit the end.

Comment: If you really need to perform searches with wildcard on both sides, I would look into using Full Text Indexes or a document database that specializes in search.  If you are only talking about a few hundred rows in a table with very limited growth potential then you probably don't need to worry too much.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
select 
    Id 
    ,[target] 
    ,[name] 
    ,[extrafield1]
    ,[extrafield2]
    ,[extrafield3]
From [inventory]
where [target] LIKE 'dil%' OR [name] LIKE '%dil%'
order by
  case when target = 'dil' then 0 else 1 end asc,
  case when name = 'dil' then 0 else 1 end asc
```

Comment: While this might get you what you want putting a %dil% will cause a serial read of the table.  Wildcards should only be placed at the end of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good use case for [IF/ELSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) statement

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [inventory]
    where [target] LIKE 'dil%')
    BEGIN
        select 
        Id 
        ,[target] 
        ,[name] 
        ,[extrafield1]
        ,[extrafield2]
        ,[extrafield3]
    From [inventory]
    where [target] LIKE 'dil%'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        select 
            Id 
            ,[target] 
            ,[name] 
            ,[extrafield1]
            ,[extrafield2]
            ,[extrafield3]
        From [inventory]
        where [name] LIKE '%dil%'
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with union..

```
select 
   Id 
   ,[target] 
   ,[name] 
   ,[extrafield1]
   ,[ Extrafield2]
   ,[extrafield3]
  From [inventory]
    where [target] LIKE 'dil%' 

  Union
   select 
  Id 
  ,[target] 
  ,[name] 
  ,[extrafield1]
  ,[extrafield2]
   ,[ Extrafield3]
  From [inventory]
  where [name] LIKE '%dil%'
```